# Add to spring an interface implementation from another jar

Tags: java, spring, service, dependency-injection

I have a "*core*" module which have an interface "*DbService*".
The implementation of that interface  is inside another module  "*MsSqlDbService*" (for different purposes I have many implementation of "*DbService*", so I just place "right" jar in the "right" place before running my program)

To load "*DbService*" I use standard java service loader `java.util.ServiceLoader<DbService>`

So I wonder: is there a way to make my spring container manage "*DbService*"?
Because now the spring container manages for me the class which actually loads implementation of "*DbService*", instead of managing "*DbService*" itself.

Comment: is MsSqlDbService managed by spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (for different purposes I have many implementation of "DbService", so
>   I just place "right" jar in the "right" place before running my
>   program)

If I understand correctly, you have multiple JARs that all contain implementations of the same interface.  You want Spring to pickup whichever one is on the classpath at deployment time and then autowire everything together correctly?

Spring can definitely be used as a "poor man's plugin framework" to accomplish this sort of thing:

1) In your main project, add this to your context:

`<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-dbService.xml"/>`

2) In each JAR, create a file named `applicationContext-dbService.xml`.  It would look something like this for the SQL Server example you provided.

```
<bean id="msSqlDbService" class="com.foo.MsSqlDbServiceImpl"/>
```

3) When your main context is loaded, Spring will scan the classpath for files named `applicationContext-dbService.xml` and then process any beans that are defined in them.  Assuming that you only have one "plugin" JAR on the classpath at deployment time, you'll be able to autowire an instance of DbService into anything in your main project.

Comment: It works. Thanks.
About  "poor man's plugin framework" - do you think it should have been done another way? I mean - Is it unusual to do things this way? Because since I new to java world I didn't know how to do it so I come up with this approach on my own.

Comment: I have a few projects that do the exact same thing using Spring.  Perfectly normal way to do things. If it works for you, go ahead and use it without worrying. What I mean by "poor man's plugin framework" is that this approach isn't as full featured as something like OSGi. For example, it doesn't handle plugin versioning, dependencies between plugins, or lifecycle events (starting/stopping/ uninstalling plugins).  However, 1) you didn't indicate you had a requirement for any of those features 2) it would be much more effort to add something like OSGi to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `DbService` interface as the member of the class.

```
class Demo{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("msSqlDbService")
private DbService dbService;

//Setter and getter
}
```

Now put the implementation classes(which you require) of `DbService` in spring xml config

```
<bean id="msSqlDbService" class="xxxx.MsSqlDbService"/>//xxxx is the package name.
```

Comment: MsSqlDbService is a class from separate jar(module) it is not a package inside a "core". So it is impossible. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I did not get what you mean. If you need to use any class from the jar you need to put in the class path of the application. And how it's impossible?